# Deployment Automation in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using Bigquery for the past 3-6 months and we have created several datastudio reports and now we are looking for ways to keep things in source control and automate deployment.

While using SQL server as RDBMS, we used [SQL Server database project](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-sql-server-database-project-with-visual-studio/) that allows keeping initial schema/data or migrations in source control and pushed them to target environment.What are our options to do something similar in Bigquery?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Cloud Source Repositories](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/) to source control for an application or service. You can use this repository to multiple private repositories and organize the code associated with your cloud project. If you have setup the Cloud Source Repository, you can use the deployment guide provided [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying/repo). If you want to load data into BigQuery, follow the guide provided [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage). You can also use an Avro data, where the data and schema is stored in the same file. When you [load Avro data from Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-avro), you have the option to create a new table or partition, append or overwrite to an existing table. You can use Cloud Container Builder to [redeploy your cloud functions automatically](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/testing#continuous_testing_and_deployment) from a source repository such as Cloud Source repositories.

Comment: We do not have cloud functions or any form of source code, we have bigquery datasets and views that we want to deploy.

Comment: Please see the documentation for managing Datasets and Views in BigQuery. Currently Datasets and Views cannot be copied, instead you have to recreate Datasets and Views. Datasets - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-datasets 
 Views - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-views