# How to keep BigQuery schema in sync with code

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, terraform, infrastructure-as-code

I am developing various services which talk directly to BigQuery, by streaming rows into the database. Right now I am updating the schema directly from the Google cloud UI, which has been causing issues as you can imagine due to forgetfulness!

I would like to understand how best to keep code & schemas aligned for what are still fast evolving services and schemas.

My current ideas are:

- use something like Terraform, but I am unsure on how this works on live tables which need updating or migrating
- add code to the service to check / set the schema, which would at least throw errors if not automate the process

Thanks in advance!

---

EDIT:

To give more clarity as request in the comments; we are using a cloud run microservices to stream rows into bigquery, the services are written in python/node. Their primary goal is to do some light transform on the data and store in BQ.

Not really sure what more to add, my ideal scenario is that we have something in the code which also defines or at least checks the schema, to keep the code and db in sync.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50813574/deployment-automation-in-bigquery

Comment: @dendog, actually Bigquery is leveraging variety of [APIs and Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries-overview) that might address a lot of efforts, even simplified `bq` [command-line](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference) tool can be good starting point to fulfill almost all Bigquery managing actions. Can you elaborate more to the initial quest to get more details about functionality expectations?

Answer (score -1):

As any databases, you have to follow some rules or best practices to avoid some errors and conflicts. For example, you have to avoir to update manually the schema, you can choose to do it always with code (which is better because you can follow the schema change thanks to your git history).

Then you can have a side process that check the schema and update it with the newer changes. Or do this at startup (only if you aren't in serverless and the app start duration isn't a concern for you).

Terraform is perfect to deploy infrastructure, but much more limited to update/patch existing components. I don't recommend it.

Comment: This answer is far too high level to help in any way.

Comment: All depends what are you looking for. Can you precise what do you want to know more or more precisely?

Comment: Actually what I am looking for is for a "precise" answer :) I have outlined the options and you re-iterated them, but really I would like a proper solution with a clear example.

Comment: It's too difficult. Depends on your workload, your context, the requirements, your language... Be precise, I would be able to be also

Comment: :) :) :) I'm not a Googler, I'm not a support, I'm an IT engineer with 15+ year of experience. Blame me as you want, I'm trying to help you. I saw different cases, constraints that can drive you in different ways. A generic solution is useless, the context matters! You have a lot of library/framework that already try to help you with schema management (with MySQL or PostgreSQL); this libraries are opinionated and you can get inspiration from them to find the way that match the most for you. Or add details!

Comment: I am not blaming you. But it is odd to write answer and when people state it does not help to blame the question. I also added more detail, what more do you need to see?